# how to change my Node-Text

Tags: c#, syncfusion

i created some symbol without Labels, after dropping my Symbols from Palette, my symbol will automatic be labeled with Text. my problem is that the first Node-Drop from every symbol i´ve created is not labeled, after the second, third, fourth, etc. Node-Drop that node will automatic assigned with Label.

Second requirement i would to know, after dropping my Node, how can i edit my nodeText. by clicking or double-clicking the node.

Here is my Code:

```
    protected void DiagramWebControl1_NodeDropFromPalette(object sender,   Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Diagram.NodeDropFromPaletteEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Node is PathNode || e.Node is Group)
       {
          PathNode node = e.Node as PathNode;
          if (node != null)
          {
            if (node.FullName == "Prozess Start")
            {
                node.Name = "Prozess Start";
                node.Labels.Add(new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Diagram.Label(node, node.Name));
            }
            else if (node.FullName == "Prozess")
            {
                node.Name = "Prozess";
                node.Labels.Add(new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Diagram.Label(node, node.Name));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Group gnode = e.Node as Group;
            if (gnode.FullName == "Organisationseinheit")
            {
                gnode.Name = "Organisationseinheit";
                gnode.Labels.Add(new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Diagram.Label(gnode, gnode.Name));
            }
            else if (gnode.FullName == "Rolle")
            {
                gnode.Name = "Rolle";
                gnode.Labels.Add(new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Diagram.Label(gnode, gnode.Name));
            }
            else if (gnode.FullName == "Externe Rolle")
            {
                gnode.Name = "Externe Rolle";
                gnode.Labels.Add(new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Diagram.Label(gnode, gnode.Name));
            }
            else if (gnode.FullName == "IT-System")
            {
                TextNode rtxNode = new TextNode("");
                rtxNode.Text = "IT-System";
                gnode.Labels.Add(new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Diagram.Label(gnode, rtxNode.Text));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Since the node’s FullName is generated uniquely by appending the ‘Model’ to the node’s name by the DiagramWebControl, check whether the dropped node’s FullName and the name given in your code are the same one. If you want to add ‘Labels’ to the node based on their names, then use the node’s ‘Name’ property instead of using FullName.
2. Refer the Syncfusion’s public forum regarding your requirement of editing nodeText in double-clicking the node.
   Here's a [link](http://www.syncfusion.com/support/forums/general/107749).

Comment: hi Amsath, thanx for your answer. there is still an open thread in the syncfusion forum about Rendering, could u check it up plz.